# Windows 10 display resolution is getting scaled

Tags: resolution, scaling, high-dpi

I'm trying to hook up my new Dell Inspiron 15 5000 to my QHD monitor and having problems with the display resolution.

The Display settings dialog (Desktop->Display Settings) lists the maximum resolution for the monitor as 2048x1152 even though it is a QHD (2560x1440) monitor. Nothing that I have done has allowed me to convince Windows to use the full QHD.

I'm pretty sure that this isn't a text scaling/HiDPI issue:

- The dropdown "Change the size of text, apps and other items" is set to 100%
- Under "Advanced scaling settings" the custom scaling is disabled
- When I connect the HDMI cable, the monitor complains that it isn't being driven at the native resolution.

The thing that is frustrating me is that 2560x1440 scaled to 125% would be the 2048x1152 resolution that I am getting. This makes me think that something, somewhere is scaling the resolution.

I've connected the monitor to two other laptops with the HDMI cable that I am using, and they were both able to drive the monitor at full QHD resolution.

I've updated the drivers for both the video card (Intel Iris Plus, as well as the monitor.

Every solution that I've found searching refers to the DPI scaling which doesn't affect the resolution that is displayed in the Display Setting panel.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it turns out that the HDMI port is being limited to 2048x1152 by Dell. The fact that this looks like 125% scaling is just a coincidence.